# Cloudera hbase indexer not working

Tags: hbase, cloudera-cdh

I'm trying to index HBase table, I followed the [instructions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-search/v1-latest/Cloudera-Search-User-Guide/csug_use_hbase_indexer_service.html), but in the end I saw a bit different info:

```
./hbase-indexer list-indexers --zookeeper 192.168.0.1:2181,192.168.0.2:2181    

my_index
    Lifecycle state: ACTIVE
    Incremental indexing state: SUBSCRIBE_AND_CONSUME
    Batch indexing state: BUILD_REQUESTED
    SEP subscription ID: null
    SEP subscription timestamp: 2014-11-17T16:25:53.629 05:00
    Connection type: solr
    Connection params:
      solr.collection = vk_groups
      solr.zk = 192.168.22.11:2181,192.168.22.12:2181/solr
    Indexer config:
      261 bytes, use -dump to see content
    Indexer component factory: com.ngdata.hbaseindexer.conf.DefaultIndexerComponentFactory
    Additional batch index CLI arguments:
      (none)
    Default additional batch index CLI arguments:
      (none)
    Processes
      0 running processes
      0 failed processes
```

0 running processes - but it must be 1 (from tutorial).
As u can see, I tried butch update, but it is frozen.
There are no logs anywhere (I've got log directory location from jog4j options).

And now I totally don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the indexer is not running.
Start indexer with command:
    /bin/hbase-indexer server